# Статический класс в сборке, независимая инициализация из разных AppDomain

Tags: c#, рефлексия, appdomain

Есть .dll, в ней статический класс, со статическими данными (заполненными полями, методами).

Задача: загрузить сборку в разные домены приложений, сделать возможность многопоточного выполнения метода из сборки, но чтобы данные не пересекались. Т.е. чтобы в каждом домене приложений использовался свой экземпляр статического класса, статические поля которого имели собственные значения, уникальные для каждого домена приложений.

Что уже есть:

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain1");
            var dll = domain.Load("TestDll");

            var type = dll.GetType("TestStaticClass");
            var method = type.GetMethod("TestStaticMethod");
            method.Invoke(null, null);

            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
         }
```

Но к сожалению, в таком варианте исполнения - данные статических полей общие для всех доменов приложения (т.е. данные пересекаются).

p.s. помечать статические поля атрибутом ThreadStatic - не предлагать. Да, в таком случае поля будут уникальными для каждого потока, но если в домене приложения два и более потоков - значения полей будут доступны только в первом потоке, в котором будет инициализирован статический конструктор, в последующих потоках поля будут иметь значения по умолчанию для каждого типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class Program
{
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void Test()
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("in domain {0}, counter = {1}",
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, counter);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain1");

            domain.DoCallBack(Test);

            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

Для случая вызова нестатического метода обычно используют `MarshalByRefObject` и `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`. Для случая статического метода достаточно простого `domain.DoCallBack`.

---

Обратите внимание на то, что `DoCallBack` работает по разному с marshal-by-ref- и marshal-by-value-объектами.

Например, такой код:

```
public class Program : MarshalByRefObject // важно!
{
    int counter = 0;

    public void Test() // не static
    {
        counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("in domain {0}, counter = {1}",
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, counter);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Test();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain1");

            domain.DoCallBack(p.Test);

            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

уже будет вызывать оба раза `Test` в одном и том же домене.

Comment: столкнулся с проблемой. Использую метод с прокси. Задача - вернуть Bitmap из метода CallStatic(). Со строкой - проблем нет. Но с битмапом выдает исключение: "Тип "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat" не помечен как сериализуемый." Пробовал разные варианты, помечал классы как сереализуемые - но к сожалению так и не удалось победить проблему.

Comment: @z668: Хм. Даже если вы сможете вернуть картинку из другого AppDomain'а, всё равно у графических объектов обычно thread affinity, то есть они могут работать только в том потоке, который их создаёт. А почему вы возвращаете именно картинку? Если она приходит из сети, можно вернуть массив байт, и создать картинку уже в нужном домене.

Comment: я просто хотел разобраться со сложными типами, такими как Bitmap. Но теперь стало ясно что это проблематично, а может быть - и невозможно. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: @z668: Маршаллирование хорошо проходит с примитивными типами, а со сложными всё хуже. Например, если объект при создании подписывается на события, и вы утаскиваете его в другой домен, куда должны приходить эти события? Всё сложно :)

Answer (score 3):

Статические переменные и так разные в разных доменах. Просто ваш код выполняет `TestStaticMethod` в основном домене - получает в основном домене `MethodInfo`, и в основном же домене вызывает `Invoke`. Механизм кросдомееных вызовов полагается на прокси-объекты, так что кросдоменно вызвать статический метод напрямую нельзя.

Для вызова статического метода в другом домене вам нужен нестатический прокси. Примерно так:

в TestDll:

```
public class TestStaticClass
{
    public static void TestStaticMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
}

public class NonStaticProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void CallStatic()
    {
        TestStaticClass.TestStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

в основном приложении:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain1");
    var dll = domain.Load("TestDll");

    var type = dll.GetType("TestStaticClass");
    var method = type.GetMethod("TestStaticMethod");
    // prints ConsoleApplication
    method.Invoke(null, null);

    var wrapper = (NonStaticProxy)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("TestDll", "NonStaticProxy");
    // prints domain1
    wrapper.CallStatic();

    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
}
```

Comment: а если статических классов сотни (а методов и того больше)? Есть какой либо универсальный подход?

Comment: передавайте имя класса и имя метода параметрами в `CallStatic` - у вас же правильный код, его просто надо перенести в метод `CallStatic`

Comment: @z668 но вообще сотни статических методов - это плохо :)

Comment: ну я для самообразования спросил. На самом деле мало информации по этой теме, а та что есть - в основном на английском. Сейчас еще проверю вариант VladD.

Comment: @z668 у Vlad вариант лучше. по крайней мере, короче.